# Como retornar a soma da coluna valor_negocio, mês a mês, com base na coluna data_inicio?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: Tabela]

Preciso de uma instrução SQL que retorne a soma da coluna valor_negocio, mês a mês, com base na coluna data_inicio.

Exemplo:

[image: Wanted OP result]

**Preciso que apareça o nome do mês e o total.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(valor_negocio),
       MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(data_inicio), '%m'))
FROM negocio
GROUP BY MONTH(data_inicio)
```

Comment: Felipe, esse codigo é sql puro ? ou seja, funciona para qualquer banco ?

Comment: @alessandremartins está utilizando funções que podem não ter em outros bancos. Você informou a tag mysql. Essas funções pertencem a ele. Obs. Atente à questão dos anos.

Comment: foi como o amigo acima mencionou, eu usei a sintaxe em mysql, pode ser que não funcione em outros bancos. Dá uma conferida.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do Henrique:

```
SELECT SUM(valor_negocio) AS SOMA, MONTH(data_inicio) AS MES 
FROM negocio GROUP BY MONTH(data_inicio)
```

Além disso, se os dados selecionados forem superiores a um ano, você também precisará agrupar por ano:

```
SELECT SUM(valor_negocio) AS SOMA, MONTH(data_inicio) AS MES 
FROM negocio GROUP BY MONTH(data_inicio), YEAR(data_inicio)
```

Answer (score 1):

Separando pelos anos, mas sem exibi-los:

```
Select
   MONTHNAME(DATE_FORMAT(data_inicio,'%Y-%m-01')) as mes,
   sum(valor_negocio)
from negocio
group by DATE_FORMAT(data_inicio,'%Y-%m-01')
order by DATE_FORMAT(data_inicio,'%Y-%m-01');
```

Mostrando os anos:

```
Select
   Year(data_inicio) as ano,
   MONTHNAME(DATE_FORMAT(data_inicio,'%Y-%m-01')) as mes,
   sum(valor_negocio)
from negocio
group by ano, DATE_FORMAT(data_inicio,'%Y-%m-01')
order by DATE_FORMAT(data_inicio,'%Y-%m-01');
```

Coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85c744/3

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia,

Tente:

```
select sum(valor_negocio) from negocio group by data_inicio
```

Comment: mas dessa forma nao vai aparecer o nome do mes, preciso que apareça

Comment: Não entendi o por que negativou a resposta , você pediu o script que retorne a soma do valor. Para exibir outros campos do banco , basta adcionar no sql , como o Anderson mostrou.